# Fragment Content Overlaps Toolbar and Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have implemented a bottom navigation view in  my android application. With five fragments. However, I have a problem that each time I change the fragment the content of the fragment overlaps the toolbar.

layout for the bottom navigation view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


       />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

an example of one of the fragments layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AttendanceFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_courses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Date" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:focusable="true" />-->

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="cardView2,tv_time"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="511dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMainBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier3">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what the screen look like with overlapping content

[image]

Comment: Change the ConstraintLayout in the top xml to CoordinatorLayout and then add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in the ConstraintLayout of the second xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add margins to container:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="{bottom_navigation_height}"
    android:layout_marginTop="{tool_bar_height}"

   />
```

Comment: I think this is a ridiculous solution (not because you suggested it, just because it being necessary). I tried everything else in this thread (I dunno, "0dp" height for me just made things disappear lol) but this was the only thing that worked. Really fricking stupid I have to manually specify a margin to get it to look right. And it's in an Activity and Fragment that is the exact same as my MainActivity, which doesn't have this problem. Only difference is my MainActivity has a fragment with a RecyclerView in it, rather than EditText/TextView widgets like this second Activity/Fragment.

Comment: FWIW, for the "include" for my app toolbar, I added "android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" and for the FragmentContainerView underneath it, I added "android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 10):

I removed from my ConstraintLayout the default generated `marginTop` field, and changed my fragment's `layout_height` to 0dp. Then in all of my Fragments' layout's the outermost `layout_height` I always set to match parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I changed my fragment's `layout_height` to `0dp` and it worked like a charm. Could anyone explain why it fixes the issue?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!!

Answer (score 3):

You should add constraints to your @id/container.
To the top to your toolbar and to the bottom to the BottomNavigationBar. The same should you do to these elements. Toolbar top to parent and toolbar bottom to container. BottomNavigationBar top to container and bottom to parent. Then set the height of the container to 0dp.

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/navigationView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Didn't test the code but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Its overlapping because You have not giving proper constraint to your controls.

***You can try this way.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Recent Android Studio Versions (4.0.beta 1), if the hierarchy on the default generated `activity_main.xml` (omitted attributes) is as following,

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView />
    <fragment />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragments seems overlapping the bottom navigation, just rearranging it as shown below,

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <fragment />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fixed the problem for me **without touching any constraints and NOT adding any padding or margins**

Answer (score 0):

Please check your MainActivity code.
In case you are using

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment)
```

use replace:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
```

'add' adds n top of fragments, 'replace' removes previous one and adds new Frag

Answer (score -1):

your fragment container used "match_parent",which take up the position of toolbar and  navigationBar,maybe you can choice nested LinearLayout and use height=warp_content, weight=1