# Bottom Navigation and Fragment is overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, bottomnavigationview

As you can see in this picture

[image]
the bottom navigation and the textfields are over lapping.

what could be the cause of this weird behavior of my app?

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.ApplicationFragment">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_amount_applied"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/amount_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:hint="Amount Applied" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="Mode of payment">
                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_term"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/term_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:hint="Term" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="INDIVIDUAL INFORMATION"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_last_name"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/lastname_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="Lastname" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_first_name"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/firstname_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="Firstname" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_middle_name"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/middlename_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="Middlename" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_birthdate"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/birthdate_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:hint="Birthdate" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/text_age"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/age_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:hint="Age" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="Sex">
                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/sex_exposed_dropdown"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is the activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.circularreveal.coordinatorlayout.CircularRevealCoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</com.google.android.material.circularreveal.coordinatorlayout.CircularRevealCoordinatorLayout>
```

by the way I just duplicated, copy and pasted 10 or mor times the Birthdate, Age and sex in order to test if the fragment is scrolling. eventually after I run the app as you can see in the picture the bottom navigation and the text fields are now overlapping.

Comment: will it be ok if you show me your XML file of main_activity where you display bottomNavigationView? Because the problem is there.

Comment: @DPrince added the xml. please check it out

Comment: Why you use CircularRevealCoordinatorLayout and where is your fragment load layout.

Comment: Is it not good to use?

Comment: If you want to use it by some purpose then it will be ok to use otherwise not good to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment Content Overlaps Toolbar and Bottom Navigation View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524647/fragment-content-overlaps-toolbar-and-bottom-navigation-view)

Answer (score 4):

let's suppose your `BottomNavigationView` height is 60dp , you can avoid this behavior by adding this attribut to your `NestedScrollView`

```
  android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
```